# FFT with Accelerometer Data

Tags: c, fft, accelerometer

I am trying to find an open source FFT solution that is written in low level C. I need to run a triple axis accelerometer coordinates through the FFT to due vibration analysis. I have looked all around through google and cannot find anything. Space is a major concern for me in because this is going on a small device. Is there any good solutions that are open source? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out my FFT implementation [libsimplefft](https://github.com/kneo/libsimplefft).

It provides a low level C API for FFT and Fast Convolutions, as well as a Java JNI Wrapper.

Its build using GNU Autobuild and an Android NDK Build target (both included).

**Look here for [example](https://github.com/kneo/libsimplefft/tree/master/example)!**

Comment: When i make my call to perform() and then check the results from the pointers to re and im. . . .my results are unrealistic, such as NAN and large positive number E35 and large negative number -1E-35.
       while(ci < vibraSettings.cycles)
 {    ...
   *re  =  (double)reading.x/INT16_MAX * 2.0;
   *im  = 0;
          sprintf(outBuffer, "Accel,%f\n",*(re));
                       Increment
  }  
 }
 perform
        while(i < vibraSettings.cycles)
        {
           sprintf(outBuffer, "Results,%f\nResults,%f\n",*(re), *(im));
    nd_uart0_putstr(outBuffer);
           Increment
         }

Comment: you are not dereferencing the pointer as far as I can see, try re[i] while i is your sample position. Also make sure you are using the right data type on initialization. using double means you need to initialize with FFT_TYPE_DP! ... I uploaded an example showing how to use it .. check it out for help ...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need [KissFFT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/). Simple, easy to use, lightweight, written in C, quite efficient, free, doesn't have all the baggage of the heavyweights like FFTW.

Comment: Yeah, kiss_fft, but be aware that it's not exactly "perfect".

Comment: @Hot Licks: I would be interested to hear details of any specific problems ?

Comment: Well, it works fairly well for an "average" case, but for some boundary conditions (eg, lots of zeros in the data) it produces results that are not consistent with more robust algorithms.

Comment: @HotLicks: please provide supporting details as a sourceforge bug. If that is true, I'd like to rectify it.

Answer (score 0):

**Fastest Fourier transform in the West**

http://www.fftw.org/

It comes with a very good documentation. For open source projects, sometimes the quality of documentation outruns quality of code...:)